# Convergence of the Implicitly Restarted Arnoldi Method (IRAM)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I know that the [Implicitly Restarted Arnoldi Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnoldi_iteration) (IRAM) consists of using the implicitly shifted [QR algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm) to restart the Arnoldi process without losing to much information about the eigenspace. In particular, taking

$$p(t) = (t-k_1 I)\cdots(t-k_{m-k}I)$$

where $k_1,\dots,k_{m-k}$ are values we are not interested in, then

$$\tilde{u}_1 = \frac{p(A)u_1}{\|p(A)u_1\|}$$

should be a good restarting vector. My question is whether the convergence of the Arnoldi method with this starting new vector is guaranteed by some theorem, or in general is just a good choice according to literature, or there are some sort of bound on the residual norm of the method, i.e $\|AV_ky -V_kH_ky\|$ and why it should converge to zero (where $y$ is the primitive Ritz vector).

Any help in understanding this would be appreciated. Matrix $A$ is non-normal (any reference would be as well appreciated though).